# MySQL connection times out after a while (Python, MySQL, FLASK)

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm currently running an flask python application running on an NGINX server with the help of uWGI. The static pages are always reachable but the pages that use a connection (MySQL) time out after 2 minutes. What's going on? They become simply become unavailable.

Things I have tried:

- Not using a global
- working with pools
- turning off firewall

.

```
# using python version 2.7.10
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
import mysql.connector.pooling

#Make a connection with the DB

dbconfig = {
  "host" : "12.34.5.78",
  "database": "db",
  "user":     "user",
  "password": "pass"
}

conn = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name = "mypool",
                      pool_size = 6,
                      **dbconfig)

#Define the root
app = Flask(__name__)

#Landings page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World."

# return all resources by name
@app.route('/resources', methods=['GET'])
def allResourceNames():
    conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name="mypool")
    reader = conn1.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT name FROM resources")
    reader.execute(query)
    resources = []
    for name in reader:
    resources.append({'name' : name[0]})
    reader.close()
    conn1.close()
    return jsonify({"resources" : resources})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MySQL Python Connector Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)
you may want to set `connection_timeout` as connect option. E.g.,

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(pool_name = "mypool",
                  pool_size = 6, connection_timeout=3600,
                  **dbconfig)
```

Comment: Could you please post the error msg you're getting in  your post? thanks

Comment: It worked by the way. But i'm not sure why. I simply changed the connection_timeout=1 and now it's actually quite a bit faster. Could you explain what's actually happening?